# Access to array in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, arraylist, multidimensional-array

How can I access `lista` and sum all: `unidades` when `Producto` matches 1 and 2?

```
[{
    "id": "3WzFN",
    "cliente": "1",
    "lista": [{
      "unidades": "2",
      "precio": "25",
      "subtotal": 100,
      "producto": "Producto 1",
      "peso": "2"
    }],
    "nombre": "Vendedor 3",
    "total": 100
  },
  {
    "id": "6Zls",
    "cliente": "2",
    "lista": [{
          "unidades": "4",
          "precio": "25",
          "subtotal": 100,
          "producto": "Producto 2",
          "peso": "2"
        }, {
          "unidades": "4",
          "precio": "25",
          "subtotal": 100,
          "producto": "Producto 1",
          "peso": "2"
          "}],"
          nombre ":"
          Vendedor 1 ","
          total ":550}, {
            "id": "U2HX",
            "cliente": "3",
            "lista": [{
              "unidades": "2",
              "precio": "25",
              "subtotal": 100,
              "producto": "Producto 1",
              "peso": "2"
              "},{"
              unidades ":"
              3 ","
              precio ":"
              25 ","
              subtotal ":100,"
              producto ":"
              Producto 3 ","
              peso ":"
              2 ""
            }],
            "nombre": "Vendedor 2",
            "total": 600
          },
          {
            "id": "Xy77",
            "cliente": "4",
            "lista": [{
              "unidades": "4",
              "precio": "25",
              "subtotal": 100,
              "producto": "Producto 2",
              "peso": "2"
            }],
            "nombre": "Vendedor 3",
            "total": 230
          },
          {
            "id": "aJixp",
            "cliente": "5",
            "lista": [{
                  "unidades": "2",
                  "precio": "25",
                  "subtotal": 100,
                  "producto": "Producto 1",
                  "peso": "2"
                  "}],"
                  nombre ":"
                  Vendedor 3 ","
                  total ":220}]
```

What I tried:

```
 const [ventasFiltradas, setVentasFiltradas] = useState([]);

 const total = ventasFiltradas.reduce(
      (valor, elemento) => valor + elemento.total,0);

      

totalUnidades = ventasFiltradas.reduce(
      (valor, elemento) => {
        return valor + elemento['lista'].reduce(
          (a,b) => a + parseInt(b['unidades']
        ), 0)
      }, 0
    );

<TableCell>$ { totalUnidades }</TableCell>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
total.flatMap(item => item.lista).filter(item => item.Producto == 1 || item.Producto == 2).map(item => item.unidades).reduce((a, b) => a+b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using `reduce`:

```
// Iterate across every top-level element
// Sum the results of every inner loop
valorTotal = total.reduce(
  (valor, elemento) => {
    // Run a reduce to get the sum of all "unidades" values
    return valor + elemento['lista'].reduce(
      (a,b) => a + parseInt(b['unidades']
    ), 0)
  }, 0
);
```

Comment: Thanks, this work, but sum all 'unidades', I need to sum when the product name matches.

Comment: Any name of producto.

Comment: What I expected: 
    
    Producto 1 = 10
    Producto 2 = 8
    Producto 3 = 3